# HDFS NFS locations using weird numerical username values for directory permissions

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Seeing nonsense values for user names in folder permissions for NFS mounted HDFS locations, while the HDFS locations themselves (using Hortonworks HDP 3.1) appear fine. Eg.

```sh
➜  ~ ls -lh /nfs_mount_root/user
total 6.5K
drwx------. 3 accumulo  hdfs    96 Jul 19 13:53 accumulo
drwxr-xr-x. 3  92668751 hadoop  96 Jul 25 15:17 admin
drwxrwx---. 3 ambari-qa hdfs    96 Jul 19 13:54 ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x. 3 druid     hadoop  96 Jul 19 13:53 druid
drwxr-xr-x. 2 hbase     hdfs    64 Jul 19 13:50 hbase
drwx------. 5 hdfs      hdfs   160 Aug 26 10:41 hdfs
drwxr-xr-x. 4 hive      hdfs   128 Aug 26 10:24 hive
drwxr-xr-x. 5 h_etl   hdfs   160 Aug  9 14:54 h_etl
drwxr-xr-x. 3    108146 hdfs    96 Aug  1 15:43 ml1
drwxrwxr-x. 3 oozie     hdfs    96 Jul 19 13:56 oozie
drwxr-xr-x. 3 882121447 hdfs    96 Aug  5 10:56 q_etl
drwxrwxr-x. 2 spark     hdfs    64 Jul 19 13:57 spark
drwxr-xr-x. 6 zeppelin  hdfs   192 Aug 23 15:45 zeppelin
➜  ~ hadoop fs -ls /user
Found 13 items
drwx------   - accumulo   hdfs            0 2019-07-19 13:53 /user/accumulo
drwxr-xr-x   - admin      hadoop          0 2019-07-25 15:17 /user/admin
drwxrwx---   - ambari-qa  hdfs            0 2019-07-19 13:54 /user/ambari-qa
drwxr-xr-x   - druid      hadoop          0 2019-07-19 13:53 /user/druid
drwxr-xr-x   - hbase      hdfs            0 2019-07-19 13:50 /user/hbase
drwx------   - hdfs       hdfs            0 2019-08-26 10:41 /user/hdfs
drwxr-xr-x   - hive       hdfs            0 2019-08-26 10:24 /user/hive
drwxr-xr-x   - h_etl    hdfs            0 2019-08-09 14:54 /user/h_etl
drwxr-xr-x   - ml1        hdfs            0 2019-08-01 15:43 /user/ml1
drwxrwxr-x   - oozie      hdfs            0 2019-07-19 13:56 /user/oozie
drwxr-xr-x   - q_etl hdfs            0 2019-08-05 10:56 /user/q_etl
drwxrwxr-x   - spark      hdfs            0 2019-07-19 13:57 /user/spark
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin   hdfs            0 2019-08-23 15:45 /user/zeppelin
```

Notice the difference for users ml1 and q_etl that they have numerical user values when running `ls` on the NFS locations, rather then their user names. 
Even doing something like...

```sh
[hdfs@HW04 ml1]$ hadoop fs -chown ml1 /user/ml1
```

does not change the NFS permissions. Even more annoying, when trying to change the NFS mount permissions as root, we see

```sh
[root@HW04 ml1]# chown ml1 /nfs_mount_root/user/ml1
chown: changing ownership of ‘/nfs_mount_root/user/ml1’: Permission denied
```

This causes real problems, since the differing uid means that I can't access these dirs even as the "correct" user to write to them. Not sure what to make of this. Anyone with more Hadoop experience have any debugging suggestions or fixes?

---

**UPDATE**:

Doing a bit more testing / debugging, found that the rules appear to be...

1. If the NFS server node has no uid (or gid?) that matches the uid of the user on the node accessing the NFS mount, we get the weird uid values as seen here.
2. If there is a uid associated to the username of the user on the requesting node, then that is the uid user that we see assigned to the location when accessing via NFS (even if that uid on the NFS server node is not actually for the requesting user), eg.

```sh
[root@HW01 ~]# clush -ab id ml1
---------------
HW[01,04] (2)
---------------
uid=1025(ml1) gid=1025(ml1) groups=1025(ml1)
---------------
HW[02-03] (2)
---------------
uid=1027(ml1) gid=1027(ml1) groups=1027(ml1)
---------------
HW05
---------------
uid=1026(ml1) gid=1026(ml1) groups=1026(ml1)
[root@HW01 ~]# exit
logout
Connection to hw01 closed.
➜  ~ ls -lh /hdpnfs/user
total 6.5K
...
drwxr-xr-x. 6 atlas     hdfs   192 Aug 27 12:04 ml1
...
➜  ~ hadoop fs -ls /user
Found 13 items
...
drwxr-xr-x   - ml1        hdfs            0 2019-08-27 12:04 /user/ml1
...
[root@HW01 ~]# clush -ab id atlas
---------------
HW[01,04] (2)
---------------
uid=1027(atlas) gid=1005(hadoop) groups=1005(hadoop)
---------------
HW[02-03] (2)
---------------
uid=1024(atlas) gid=1005(hadoop) groups=1005(hadoop)
---------------
HW05
---------------
uid=1005(atlas) gid=1006(hadoop) groups=1006(hadoop)
```

If wondering why I have, user on the cluster that have varying uids across the cluster nodes, see the problem posted here: [How to properly change uid for HDP / ambari-created user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57404034/8236733) (note that these odd uid setting for hadoop service users was set up by Ambari by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with someone more knowledgeable in HDP hadoop, found that the problem is that when [Ambari](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.3.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/launching_the_ambari_install_wizard.html) was setup and run to initially install the hadoop cluster, there may have been other preexisting users on the designated cluster nodes.

**Ambari creates its various service users by giving them the next available UID of a nodes available [block of user UIDs](http://www.linfo.org/uid.html)**. However, prior to installing Ambari and HDP on the nodes, I created some users on the *to-be* namenode (and others) in order to do some initial maintenance checks and tests. I should have just done this as root. Adding these extra users offset the UID counter on those nodes and so as Ambari created users on the nodes and incremented the UIDs, it was starting from different starting counter values. Thus, the UIDs did not sync and caused problems with HDFS NFS.

To fix this, I...

1. Used Ambari to stop all running HDP services
2. Go to Service Accounts in Ambari and copy all of the expected service users name strings
3. For each user, run something like `id <service username>` to get the group(s) for each user. For service groups (which may have multiple members), can do something like `grep 'group-name-here' /etc/group`. I recommend doing it this way as the Ambari docs of default users and groups does not have some of the info that you can get here.
4. Use `userdel` and `groupdel` to remove all the Ambari service users and groups
5. Then recreate all the groups across the cluster
6. Then recreate all the users across the cluster (may need to specify UID if nodes have other users not on others)
7. Restart the HDP services (hopefully everything should still run as if nothing happend, since **HDP should be looking for the literal string (not the UIDs)**)

For the last parts, can use something like clustershell, eg.

```sh
# remove user
$ clush -ab userdel <service username>
# check that the UID you want to use is actually available on all nodes
$ clush -ab id <some specific UID you want to use>
# assign that UID to a new service user
$ clush -ab useradd --uid <the specific UID> --gid <groupname> <service username>
```

To get the lowest common available UID from each node, [used](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5684/determine-next-available-uid)...

```sh
# for UID
getent passwd | awk -F: '($3>1000) && ($3<10000) && ($3>maxuid) { maxuid=$3; } END { print maxuid+1; }'
# for GID
getent passwd | awk -F: '($4>1000) && ($4<10000) && ($4>maxuid) { maxuid=$4; } END { print maxuid+1; }'
```

Ambari also creates some `/home` dirs for users. Once you are done recreating the users, will need to change the permissions for the dirs (can also use something like clush there as well).

* Note that this was a huge pain and you would need to manually correct the UIDs of users whenever you added another cluster node. I did this for a test cluster, but for production (or even a larger test) you should just useKerberos or SSSD + Active Directory.